# Incorrect laser_geometry PointCloud2 fields

Tags: ros, pcl, laser-geometry, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current laser_geometry package fails to set the 'count' members of sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::fields in projectLaser(). When using PCL 1.6 (not 1.5!) this causes incompatibility when converting PointCloud2s created from the laser package to native PCL pointclouds.

I wouldn't mind sending in a proposed patch sometime later but it isn't exactly spelled out how to go about contributing to official stacks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43987/incorrect-laser_geometry-pointcloud2-fields/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2012-09-17**:
Could you please clarify what you mean by 'count' field?  Is it missing a 'channel', such as x or intensity?  Are the settings for point.step or row.step incorrect?  Are the height and width incorrect?

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2012-09-18**:
It's the 'count' member which is within each channel. (http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointField.html)  If it's not set, it defaults to zero, and pcl 1.6 assumes non-zero counts in each channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you [submit a ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket) at code.ros.org and attach the patch, the maintainers should integrate it eventually.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2012-09-17**:
Do ros answers credentials work there?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-09-17**:
No, you must create a separate account.